# Oracle XMLDB working with big files

Tags: xml, transformation, oracle11gr2

Hi there I´m currently working with Oracle 11.2 XE and trying to do some performance tests when working with big xml files. So far I didnt get very far, hope you can help me out a little bit.

My goal is to efficiently transform large xml documents from one xml format to another inside the database, therefore I set my hopes on the XMLType binary and XMLType Object relational datatypes which should be performance optimized because Oracle says they don´t need DOM parsing for evaluationg XPath expressions in most cases.

Problem No.1 is I cant get my complex schema registered for the OR XMLTYPE. After an hour registering time it interrupts with an out of memory error at around 1.3 GB memory allocation. The schema is already broken down in 3 files, the file that triggers the out of mem error is only 80kb big. How should I handle this? Further breakdown in more connected schema files via includes?

Problem No.2 is I cant get an XMLTransform to work. I´m using

```
Insert into OUTPUT_BINARY SELECT a.filename, XMLtransform( a.xml, b.stylesheet )
FROM XMLTYPE_BINARY a, stylesheets b
  WHERE (a.filename = 'test.xml' and b.filename = 'stylesheet.xsl');
```

Where Table XMLTYPE_BINARY and OUTPUT_BINARY is

```
create table XMLTYPE_BINARY (filename varchar2(50), xml XMLTYPE) 
XMLTYPE Column xml store as BINARY XML
```

Even for a 100KB document it takes forever to transform (I terminated at 30 min dont know if it would have ever ended) when trying with 5MB document it gives me an ORA-24331: user buffer too small. Could somebody please give me a hint what I´m missing here?

Comment: Question too dumb or noone an idea?

Answer (score 0):

I thought this could probably be a limitation of the XE Version but on Oracle 11gR2 it´s the same. I tried dbms_xslprocessor instead of XMLTYPE´s XMLTransform, I indexed the Binary XMLTYPE Column via XMLINDEX but it´s still taking too long to process, a 100 KB file over 10 minutes (never saw one finish, always terminated prematurely).

I already transformed the same documents with the XDK parser and processor outside the database with a java application and could achieve good results. So why is the parser and transformer inside the db working so poorly?